# how to get the entry url on the page, after navigation?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, parameters

I have the following scenario:

I want to pass a parameter to a page`foo.com?bar=x`, but `foo.com` automatically redirects based on language to `foo.com/en` and I am loosing the `bar` parameter.

I don't mind I'm in `foo.com/en`, I just want the `bar` parameter.

The `Referer` solution does not work, as it automatically redirects, and it's the one before `foo.com?bar=x`.

Is there a JavaScript or jQuery solution to this problem?

**edit**

I just have a script on the page, `foo.com` is not my domain, I have the script on both  `foo.com` and `foo.com/en`. The problem is that on `foo.com` the script does not get called, and on `foo.com/en` I don't have the parameters any more.

The page `foo.com` redirects by this method:
`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=foo.com/en" />`

I can't modify this method, and I don't want to, as the solution would not be generic.

Comment: How is the redirection done? Who does the redirection?

Comment: `foo.com` does the redirection, I just have a script an all the pages, the problem is that on `foo.com?bar=x` it does not get do run, and on `foo.com/en` it does run, but I don't have the param any more

Comment: OK so the question is, how does foo.com do the redirection? Is it a host that does this automatically for you? Do you have any control over it? In other words, can you please provide some details about the mechanics of the redirection, if you know it?

Comment: I can't think of a single non-malicious reason why you would have a script running on `foo.com` and not be able to talk to the owner of `foo.com` about it.

Comment: One reason would be that it is not so cool to tell everybody take this script, but also modify your page. Talking to the owner would have been the last option, I'm happy that I found the fragment identifier solution, which works perfect. It was not such a big problem, it clearly had a clean way to solve. I saw Google Analytics using the same practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was much easier, just change from

`foo.com?bar=x`

to

`foo.com#bar=x`

This way, the hash tag remains, so I have `foo.com/en#bar=x`

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

If *foo.com?bar=x* and foo.com?*bar=y* should have different content, then they shouldn't redirect to the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the redirect so that it includes anything after the domain name e.g. the script name, querystring, etc. in the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP catch...
If you have

`foo.com?bar=x`

and you want to redirect to

`foo.com/en?bar=x`

use this

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=foo.com/en?bar=<?php echo $_GET["bar"]; ?>" />`

the resulting redirect will be

`foo.com/en?bar=x`